# atof conflict while compiling code

Tags: c, mingw, atof

I have just begun my journey with C programming. I have a problem with a lib conflict. Please find my sample code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAXLINE 100


//int getline declaration is here (removed for simplicity)

int main()
{
    double sum, atof(char []);
    char line[MAXLINE];
    int getline(char line[], int max);

    sum=0;
    while (getline(line,MAXLINE)>0)
        printf("\t%g\n", sum += atof(line));
40mi    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code I get a following compilation error:

> Error: conflicting types for 'atof'

I'm using CodeBlocks + mingw c compiler

**Edit** (in response to comment):

I want to download one argument and may return a `double` value , `atof` works without `stdlib.h` , but can not define `getline`

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with that `atof` declaration?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to declare `atof` if you include stdlib. It is declared in stdlib. The definition of atof in stdlib is `double atof(const char *nptr)`. It is different of yours and this explains the conflict.

getline is defined in stdio.h and expects three arguments: `ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream)`. You can't read from standard input with getline as you do. you have to use `getline(line, MAXLINE, stdin)`. And don't declare it in main because it is already declared in stdio.h.

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of `atof()` in `<stdlib.h>` is:

```
double atof (const char* str);
```

And you are declaring it as

```
double atof(char []);
```

The two declarations are **different**, hence, the error.